# NodeJS check typeOf node/module (Puppeteer)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, require, instanceof, typeof

i am struggling with type checking at nodejs.
I plan to use the library Puppeteer to test my own web pages. For this I would like to check in the methods that the function arguments have the correct type.

How do I access the type "Page" from the module "Puppeteer"?

Here's a code example

```js
const pup = require('puppeteer');

/**
 * 
 * @param {puppeteer.page} page Puppeter Browser Page (Tab)
 */
async function navigateToPage(page){
    if(page instanceof page) throw("The passed variable page is not typeOf puppeteer.page")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did this to get the class name :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log(page.constructor.name);
    process.exit(0);
    // show Page
})();
```

And i found a file in source code defining this class :

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/Page.ts

but when i explore the node module folder i found it here :
'puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page'

nevertheless, this code seems to work.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const {Page} = require('puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log(page instanceof Page);

})();
```

what do you try to achieve with that ?

Comment: that works for me. thank you!
I want to enable the autocompletion from my ide (visual studio code) and also checking, that the passed argument 'page' is from the right class